# Why can I not parse my simple YAML file without yielding the error "mapping values are not allowed here"?

Tags: python, parsing, yaml

I am trying to open, parse, then pass my YAML file into a dict in my Python script. However, I can't seem to format the file itself in a simple text editor that will allow it to parsed. I keep getting the error `mapping values are not allowed here` at the same position within the YAML text file. I have tried to reformat it in various ways, but I keep getting the same error in the same place. My code is set up like so:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import ruamel.yaml as ry

with open("yamltest2.yaml", 'r') as stream:
    try:
        print(ry.load(stream, Loader= ry.Loader))
    except ry.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)
```

And my YAML text file itself is set up like so (note: my IDE informs me that the error's source always occurs at the end of the line with `name:`):

```
input = """\
name: 
    a: 1 # comment
    b: 2
    c: 3
    d: 4
"""
```

Could anybody help me determine what the root cause for this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing Python and YAML in your `yamltest2.yaml`. Instead of

```
input = """\
name: 
    a: 1 # comment
    b: 2
    c: 3
    d: 4
"""
```

your .yaml file should look like:

```
name: 
    a: 1 # comment
    b: 2
    c: 3
    d: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Your IDE might be parsing the full error that you got, `ruamel.yaml` errors on this with the exact location where your file goes wrong:

```
mapping values are not allowed here
  in "yamltest2.yaml", line 2, column 5
```

This is because you start the YAML file with a scalar 'input = """\ name' (the  `\` here is **not** an escaping backslash) that spans multiple (two) lines, but then use that scalar as a key in a mapping. That is not allowed in YAML.

If you would want to have that exact a key, you could just specify:

```
input = """\ name:
    a: 1 # comment
    b: 2
    c: 3
    d: 4
```

you would have to remove the trailing `"""` from the file though, as that is an incomplete key without a value, throwing another error.

But this is not what you intended, you probably tried to outsource the embedded YAML string from a program like:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import ruamel.yaml as ry

input = """\
name: 
    a: 1 # comment
    b: 2
    c: 3
    d: 4
"""

try:
    print(ry.load(input, Loader= ry.Loader))
except ry.YAMLError as exc:
    print(exc)
```

and while editing copy and pasted all of the deleted lines into your YAML. As @errata already indicated, that is not YAML. If you cannot immediately resolve those issues yourself, you can of course ask here on [so], but a trick that often helps pinpoint what is going wrong is *deleting everything starting with the error point* and examining what data you load when that the truncated YAML loads without problem. In your case your YAML would need to be truncated to:

```
input = """\
name
```

which loads as the string `input = """\ name` and not as the dict as you expected.

However there is another issues with your code that you should solve: You should not use the standard `load()`. There is a reason why I raise a warning in `ruamel.yaml` when you use `load()` unadorned, as using `load()` is dangerous. You can get rid of the warning doing `load(stream, Loader=ruamel.yaml.Loader)` as you do, or suppress the warning with:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('ignore', ruamel.yaml.error.UnsafeLoaderWarning)
```

But I repeat here what I recommend in the warning message `ruamel.yaml` gives, when called unadorned: use `safe_load()`. **There is no reason for you not to do so**:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import ruamel.yaml as ry

with open("yamltest2.yaml", 'r') as stream:
    try:
        print(ry.safe_load(stream))
    except ry.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)
```